# Get object only when relation counts result is more then 0 [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have a problem with get data only when relation query count is more than 0.

This is my model of **customer** with relation

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';

    public function contracts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contract');
    }
```

This is my model of **contracts**

```
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

On the end i need only customers who they contracts beetwen some date

```
$customers = Customer::with(['contracts' => function($query)
     {
        $query->where('data_end','>=','2017-07-01')
              ->where('data_end','<=','2017-07-31') 
              ->where('typ','=','U') ;
     }
    ])->paginate(10);
```

But i have all customers. and it looks like this:

```
"Customer 1"
"Customer 2"
"Customer 3"
  *"Contract 1"
  *"Contract 2"
  *"Contract 3"
"Customer 4"
  *"Contract 1"
  *"Contract 2"
  *"Contract 3"  
"Customer 4"
```

In this example i don't need customer 1,2, and 5. How can i do it with eager loading and object with relation on the end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xwau.png)

This is happen, i dont need customer with X on the screenshot - I mean, I don't need customer with 0 contracts from where query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$customers = Customer::with('contracts')
    ->whereHas('contracts', function ($q) {
        $q->where('data_end','>=','2017-07-01')
          ->where('data_end','<=','2017-07-31') 
          ->where('typ', U');
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: so close. This query return me only this customer they have contracts but -return with all ("where" doesnt work propertly)

Comment: @underface it's just an example. If you also want filter contracts by same dates, just use `with` part from your question and `whereHas` part from my answer. It'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this query solve my problem

```
$customers = Customer::with(['contracts' => function($query)
 {
    $query->where('data_end','>=','2017-07-01')
      ->where('data_end','<=','2017-07-31') 
      ->where('typ', 'U');
 }
])->whereHas('contracts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('data_end','>=','2017-07-01')
      ->where('data_end','<=','2017-07-31') 
      ->where('typ', 'U');
})
->paginate(10)
```